# 子オブジェクトの保持していないコンポーネントの取得について

Tags: c#, unity3d

親オブジェクトに以下のようなスクリプトを置いて、子オブジェクトのRendererコンポーネントを取得したいと思いました。
しかし、子オブジェクトすべてがRendererコンポーネントを保持しているわけではないので、MissingComponentExceptionが出てしまいました。

```
void GetMaterial(GameObject gameobject)
{

    if (gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>()?.material != null)
    {
        _materials.Add(gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material);
    }

    foreach (Transform child in gameObject.GetComponents<Transform>())
    {
        GetMaterial(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

どのようにしたらRendererコンポーネントを持っているオブジェクトだけを対象とし、エラーの出ない実装にできるでしょうか。
回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

UnityのエディターではGetComponentの結果はフェイクnullです。
フェイクnullは比較オペレーターをオーバーロードしたことで、実はnullじゃないです。
それから、エディターでNullReferenceExceptionの代わりにMissingComponentExceptionが出ることができます。
nullオペレーターは==や!=オペレーターと違います。オーバーロードができないです。

```
void GetMaterial(GameObject gameobject)
{
    var renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    if (renderer != null && renderer.material != null)
    {
        _materials.Add(renderer.material);
    }

    foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform)
    {
        GetMaterial(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

日本語で説明は大変ですね。